# Getting a specific file from requested iframe

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I want to get the file link from the anime I'm watching from the site.

```
`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

page = requests.get("http://naruto-tube.org/shippuuden-sub-219")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
inner_content = requests.get(soup.find("iframe")["src"])

print(inner_content.text)`
```

the output is the source code from the filehoster's website (ani-stream). However, my problem now is how to i get the "file: xxxxxxx" line to be printed and not the whole source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Beautiful Soup to parse the iframe source code and find the script elements, but from there you're on your own.  The `file: "xxxxx",` line is in JavaScript code, so you'll have to find the function call (to `playerInstance.setup()` in this case) and decide which of the two such "file:" lines is the one you want, and strip away the unwanted JS syntax around the URL.

Regular expressions will help with that, and you're probably better off just looking for the lines in the iframe's HTML.  You already have `re` imported, so I just replaced your last line with:

```
lines = re.findall("file: .*$", inner_content.text, re.MULTILINE)
print( '\n'.join(lines) )
```

...to get a list of lines with "file:" in them.  You can (and should) use a fancier RE to find just the one with `"http://` and allows only whitespace before "file:" on the lines.  (Python, Java and my text editor all have different ideas about what's in an RE, so I have to go to docs every time I write one.  You can do that too--it's your problem, after all.)

The requests.get() function doesn't seem to work to get the bytes.  Try Vishnu Kiran's `urlretrieve` approach--maybe that will work.  Using the URL in a browser window does seem to get the right video, though, so there may be a user agent and/or cookie setting that you'll have to spoof.

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe's source is not the primary domain of the website(naruto-tube.org) its contents cannot be accessed via scraping.

You will have to use a different website or you will need to get the url in the Iframe and use some library like requests to call the url.

Note you must also pass all parameters to the url if any to actually get any result. Like so

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve ("url from the Iframe", "mp4.mp4")
```

Comment: how can i get the url in the iframe?

Comment: Inspect your page source and navigate to the iframe